# Is it possible to make a SQL 'IF' statement on all fields with the 'asterisk' character?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I can do:

```
select if(myField = 0,'', concat(myField, ' euro(s)')) from myTable;
```

But what I'd like to do is something more like

```
select if(* = 0,'', concat(*, ' euro(s)')) from myTable ;
```

i.e. for ANY field...
How would you do ?

Comment: You can't......

Comment: Nope. Not possible in SQL.